# Стек вызовов visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Имеется рекурсивный метод. Так вот, при больших входных значения получаем stack overflow. Можно ли visual studio  увеличить объем стека вызовов, или метод надо переписать итерационно?

Comment: И то, и другое :)

Comment: @Abyx, а как же флаги компоновщика?

Comment: Господа. Так я и использовал флаг /F, но прироста не дало.

Comment: Переписывайте. Сколько бы вы не увеличивали стек -- рекурсия сожрёт всё.